# Using R: Multiplying a matrix by its transpose while ignoring missing values

Tags: r, matrix

The following example may explain what I want to do and you may know a trick that would efficiently do it. Using R, preferably without looping, I would like to multiply, for instance, this matrix:

```
1  2
NA 3
4  5
```

By its transpose:

```
1 NA 4
2 3  5
```

And get (where NA was ignored):

```
(1x1)+(2x2)  (2x3)   (1x4)+(2x5)
   (3x2)     (3x3)      (3x5)
(4x1)+(5x2)  (5x3)   (4x4)+(5x5)
```

Which is:

```
05  06  12
06  09  15
14  15  41
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace NAs by 0s, so that their product don't contribute to the result:

```
m1 = matrix(c(1,NA,4,2,3,5),ncol=2)
m1[is.na(m1)] = 0
m2 = t(m1)
m1%*%m2
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5    6   14
[2,]    6    9   15
[3,]   14   15   41
```